# Bootstrap 4 - dynamic number of centered columns with fixed margin

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would like to have a set of dynamic number of colums, with a fixed size margin, to be centered in my container. I am using bootstrap 4.0.
I´ve googled for some time now, but can´t find the right solution.

Currently i have this markup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">1</div>
        <div class="col">2</div>
        <div class="col">3</div>
        <div class="col">4</div>
        <div class="col">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With five columns it results in this which is great:
[image]

But with four columns it results in this:
[image]

But this is what I would like to achieve:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Comment: I´m so bad at googling I guess :(
It works perfectly, thanks!